# How to Call "Open with Explorer" From Custom Code?

Tags: 2010, document-library

I have a custom layouts page that contains a custom visual WebPart. This WebPart wraps a `XsltListViewWebPart` with a toolbar. The toolbar is supplied as a `RenderingTemplate`. The `XsltListViewWebPart` provides a view on a document library. So far, everything works.

My problem is: that toolbar needs a button that when clicked calls the SharePoint "Open with Explorer" command that you get in the Ribbon menu of a document library.

```
<wssuc:SPToolBarButton runat="server" 
                       ID="tbbOpenWithExplorer" 
                       Text="Open with Explorer" 
                       OnClientClick="**???**" />
```

How can I call the "Open with Explorer" command?

Comment: Why not trace what JS calls get made when you click the button from a document library? Then you can just copy the calls. You can do this in the F12 Developer Tools.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to CoreInvoke a function called NavigateHttpFolder to achieve this.

Try using this script:

```
OnClientClick = "javascript:CoreInvoke('NavigateHttpFolder', yourHttpPathToOpen, '_blank');"
```

this is how the SP ribbon calls the Open With Explorer function. Search for NavigateHTTPFolder in view-source to check it out :)