# open in explorer programmatically in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, open-with-explorer

I am looking for a solution similar to:
[How to Call "Open with Explorer" From Custom Code?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43328/how-to-call-open-with-explorer-from-custom-code)
and
http://sharepoint.hannahswain.eu/2013/04/26/using-the-open-in-explorer-link-on-sharepoint-2013/

but for Online version.

When I am trying to use Script Editor web part and insert the code above, SPO seems to "eat up" part of the code, so I am guessing it does not comply with the security measures/sandbox solutions model.

When inspecting the element on the default "Open in Explorer" button, I get this:

```
'Command':'OpenWithExplorer','ClickScript':'CoreInvoke\\u0028\\u0027NavigateHttpFolder\\u0027,\\u0027https:\\\\u002f\\\\u002ftenant.sharepoint.com\\\\u002fsites\\\\u002fTeamsitewithLibraries\\\\u002fShared Documents\\u0027, \\u0027_blank\\u0027\\u0029;','HiddenScript':'!\\u0028SupportsNavigateHttpFolder\\u0028\\u0029\\u0029','LabelText':'Open with Windows Explorer','Description':'Drag and drop files into this library.'
```

so the function does seem to be similar, judging by the parameters.

Any advice?

Comment: May be you forgot to add  type="text/javascript" to your script tag.

Comment: No, would be happy if that was it, but no :)

Answer (score 1):

Either of below should work

CoreInvoke('NavigateHttpFolder',https:u002fu002example.sharepoint.comu002ftemplateu002fSharedu0020Documents', '_blank')

Or

NavigateHttpFolder('https:u002fu002example.sharepoint.comu002ftemplateu002fSharedu0020Documents', 'blank')